# How to create an output folder in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I imported an eclipse plugin with Maven nature in eclipse and after a clean on all subprojects the first warning that I saw was `source.bin build entry is missing`(because it was written in `build.properties` but missing from hard drive). I tried to create it manually ( right-click->new->folder), but then I get another warning: `bin/ is not an output folder`.
How can I create a valid `output` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select project and press `alt` + `enter` then select build path   (or right click to project and build path->configure). In source tab you can see output folder. You can press edit and select another folder.

Comment: Ok, pretty confusing warning and a more confusing solution. Thanks you for the answer!